# How to create parameter which should implement multiple interfaces in expression tree?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I want to create parameter (instance of ParameterExpression class), which should implement multiple interfaces (let they are IComparable, IFormattable) like that:

```
//TypeWithIComparableIFormattable composite_type = ...;
ParameterExpression parameter = Parameter(composite_type, "composite_param");
// Usage specific methods of composite param from implemented interfaces
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that a variable/parameter can be an instance of different types, you cannot delcare it like this:

```
IComparable, IFormattable obj;
```

To do multi-interface implementation check, you may:

1. Delcare your own interface, say `IComparableAndFormattable`, inheriting from `IComparable` and `IFormattable`. But this approach requires that the type of parameter must implement the interface.
2. Perform a runtime check. It's wordy, but keeps the code staying flexible:

Use `Expression.TypeAs()` method to convert your parameter to the desired type.

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "o");
// IComparable comparable;
var comparableDeclare = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IComparable), "comparable");
// comparable = o as IComparable;
var comparableAssign = Expression.Assign(comparableDeclare, Expression.TypeAs(param, typeof(IComparable)));
// if (comparable == (IComparable)null) 
// {
//    throw new ArgumentException("The parameter must be a instance of IComparable.", nameof(o));
// }
var comparableCheck = Expression.IfThen(Expression.Equal(comparableDeclare, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(IComparable))),
     ThrowNotTypeOf(typeof(IComparable), param.Name));

var formattableDeclare = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IFormattable), "formattable");
// formattable = o as IFormattable;
var formattableAssign = Expression.Assign(formattableDeclare, Expression.TypeAs(param, typeof(IFormattable)));
// if (formattable == (IFormattable)null) 
// {
//    throw new ArgumentException("The parameter must be a instance of IFormattable.", nameof(o));
// }
var formattableCheck = Expression.IfThen(
    Expression.Equal(formattableDeclare, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(IFormattable))),
    ThrowNotTypeOf(typeof(IFormattable), param.Name));

var block = Expression.Block(
    new [] {
        comparableDeclare, formattableDeclare
    }, // local variables
    comparableAssign, comparableCheck, formattableAssign, formattableCheck);

foreach (var exp in block.Expressions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exp);
}


// Compile the expression tree
var method = Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(block, param).Compile();

method.Invoke(new ComparableFormattable());
```

where `ThrowNotTypeOf` is a helper method generating a `throw new ArgumentException`statement:

```
private static Expression ThrowNotTypeOf(Type type, string paramName)
{
    var ctor = typeof(ArgumentException).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
    Debug.Assert(ctor != null);

    var messageArg = Expression.Constant($"The parameter must be an instance of '{type.Name}'.");
    var paramArg = Expression.Constant(paramName);

    return Expression.Throw(Expression.New(ctor, messageArg, paramArg));
}
```

Comment: Interesting point. As I understood. You suggest to use as operator in places, which require specific interface